# gtest - ensure that a method is not called before, but can be called after a certain method call

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

How can I test that `setState()` method is not called before `subscribe()`, while allowing but not forcing it to be called after?

The code below shows what I want to achieve.

This is the method I want to test:

```
...

void FirstState::enter()
{
    mInfoSubscription.subscribe(mInfoListener);

    mStateMachine.setState(mFactory.makeState(StateId::SecondState));
}

...
```

This is a unit test:

```
class FirstStateTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    FirstStateTest()
        : mFirstState{mMockStateMachine, mMockStatesFactory,
                      mMockInfoSubscription, mMockInfoListener}
    {
    }

    NiceMock<MockStateMachine> mMockStateMachine;
    NiceMock<MockStatesFactory> mMockStatesFactory;
    NiceMock<MockInfoSubscription> mMockInfoSubscription;
    NiceMock<MockInfoListener> mMockInfoListener;

    FirstState mFirstState;
};

TEST_F(FirstStateTest, ensure_that_subscription_is_done_before_state_change)
{
    // This method must not be called before "subscribe()".
    EXPECT_CALL(mMockStateMachine, doSetState(_)).Times(0);  // doesn't work the way I want

    EXPECT_CALL(mMockInfoSubscription, subscribe(_)).Times(1);

    // At this moment it doesn't matter if this method is called or not.
    EXPECT_CALL(mMockStateMachine, doSetState(_)).Times(AtLeast(0));  // doesn't work the way I want

    mFirstState.enter();
}

// other unit tests ...
...
```

**Edit 1:**

Just in case, this is how `MockStateMachine` looks:

```
class MockStateMachine : public IStateMachine {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(doSetState, void(IState* newState));
    void setState(std::unique_ptr<IState> newState) { doSetState(newState.get()); }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`::testing::InSequence`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md#ordered-vs-unordered-calls) to ensure the expected calls are in order.

```
TEST_F(FirstStateTest, ensure_that_subscription_is_done_before_state_change) {
  InSequence expect_calls_in_order;

  // `subscribe` must be called first.
  EXPECT_CALL(mMockInfoSubscription, subscribe(_)).Times(1);

  // After the `subscribe` call, expect any number of SetState calls.
  EXPECT_CALL(mMockStateMachine, doSetState(_)).Times(AtLeast(0));

  mFirstState.enter();
}
```

Comment: `InSequence` is an easy way to declare the order, but it applies to all `EXPECT_CALL`s in its scope. If you need a more flexible way of specifying order, use `Sequence`, see https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#expecting-partially-ordered-calls